# D3 Horizontal Bar Chart exact copy

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

Just started working with d3 and need to make a horizontal bar chart exactly like the one in the image for a project. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

[Image of bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNCim.png)

So far I have been working through [this](http://curran.github.io/screencasts/introToD3/examples/viewer/#/105) example and trying to adapt it to look like what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you started....

You can replace the data with some json or something

```
data = [
    {label:"new", value:10},
    {label:"repeat", value:55},
    {label:"loyal", value:35},
];
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/uzRkw1bNZfQDFfQsOh4t?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below link to start the horizontal bar chart. it's in d3.v4 version.

- change the graph margin to reduce the size of svg

[HorizontalBarChart](https://bl.ocks.org/caravinden/eb0e5a2b38c8815919290fa838c6b63b)